# problem using sqlite in QT4.7

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, qt4, qt-creator

I wrote a program using sqlite but when I run it there seems no sqlite support

Here is the information given by the QT creator:
QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers:

no available drivers!But there are sqlite4.dll,sqlodbc4.dll in the C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\plugins\sqldrivers directory why the program cannot detect where the drivers are? Should I recompile the Qt4.7 with -qt-sql-sqlite option? This seems the last resolution which is very time-consuming. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you didn't compile qt with sql enabled then sql won't work.  I would suggest you do that even though it may be time consuming.  If you need it, that is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put `qsqlite4.dll`  file within your `sqldrivers`  folder

Answer (score 1):

What mode are you builing in - debug or release? If you're building in debug mode then you need debug version of the SQLite plugin called sqlite**d**4.dll not sqlite4.dll.
You can turn some useful debug info on by setting environment variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`. If you do this and you'll get something like this

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt/4.7.0-mingw/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlite4.dll"
In C:/Qt/4.7.0-mingw/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlite4.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library
  expected build key "Windows mingw debug full-config", got "Windows mingw release full-config"
```

you know you need debug version of the plugin.

Additionally, if there's some problem with finding plugins in the original plugins' folder (the one you gave in your question) you can create `sqldrivers` folder in the folder of your app and copy `sqlite*.dll` plugins there.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably as simple as forgetting to specify the driver in the opening call:

```
QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE")
```